# ImportError with _event.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When trying to use the `kivy-module`, I get the following prompt:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/paul/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-01-06_83.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.1 (main, Dec 18 2021, 23:53:45) [GCC 11.1.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/bin/python"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/frontend/graphical_user_interface.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 411, in <module>
     from kivy.base import runTouchApp, async_runTouchApp, stopTouchApp
   File "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 29, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
 ImportError: /home/paul/PycharmProjects/finance_app/venv/lib/python3.10/
   site-packages/kivy/_event.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
   undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies, restarting, selecting different interpreters and I really don't know what else I could try - I really appreciate any help on this :)

I run the latest Linux Manjaro.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Python 3.10 then this will definitely happen. Kivy does not yet support Python 3.10, try using 3.9.
You can check out [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases) article to know all supported releases.